# Why is this printing the memory address of array

Tags: java, arrays

So this first code returns the memory address of the integer array, but I want it to print out the actual array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class FinalsReview{
int[] list = new int[]{12, 435,546, 7, 24, 4, 6, 45, 21, 1};
public static void main(String[]args){
    FinalsReview hello = new FinalsReview();
    System.out.print(hello.create());
}
public int[] create(){
    Arrays.toString(list);
    return list;
    }
}
```

However, the following code prints the actual array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class FinalsReview{
int[] list = new int[]{12, 435,546, 7, 24, 4, 6, 45, 21, 1};
public static void main(String[]args){
    FinalsReview hello = new FinalsReview();
    hello.create();
}
public void create(){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
}
```

Why does the first one return the memory address?

Answer (score 6):

it is not memory address, it is the `hashCode()` and classname that is how `toString()` is defined in [`Object`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html), when you don't specify `toString()` method for `int[]` class you inherit it from `Object`

and that is implemented like

```
public String toString() {
 return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

while this `Arrays.toString(list)` is explicitly iterates over the `Collection` and printing value of each element

and why that [from http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4168079](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4168079)

> One caveat: the toString() method is often used in printing diagnostics.
>   One would have to be careful if very large arrays were involved.  The
>   Lisp language deals with this using the print-level/print-length mechanism.
>   Something similar would be needed in Java as well.   In practice, the
>   'toString'  method provided in every class should be preferred as the
>   brief option suitable for use in concise diagnostics, and a more verbose
>   representation provided by additional application-specific conversion methods
>   if needed by the application logic.
>
> Regardless of its technical merit, however, it is doubtful that we can make
>   such a change at this late date due to compatibility/stability concerns.
>
> william.maddox@Eng 1998-08-31
>
> I concur.  It would definitely have been the right thing in 1.0, or
>   maybe even 1.1, but it's almost certainly too late for all of these changes
>   except perhaps the toString change.  One consolation is that it's amazingly easy

Comment: This doesn't really the answer of why the two code samples have different output.

Comment: It kind of does and doesn't...clarification on the fact the OP is printing the array itself and not it's contents would make it better (not the down voter)

Comment: added some header and footer to support statement better

Comment: I take the question to mean "why does it not return not I expected", not "why does it return this particular kind of output". For that, the key is in the types returned, not the technical details of `Object.toString`.

Comment: Um, and? I never said you were wrong, just that this information doesn't answer this particular question.

Comment: I mean I informed why it is not there by design

Comment: The OP already found the utility function for turning an array into a string, and used it in both code samples, they just made a mistake in *how* they used it in the first one. That quote explains why they need the utility function in the first place, but not their mistake in how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're returning the array from the method `create`, and when you attempt to print it, the display is what Jigar Joshi described. Simply calling `Arrays.toString(list)` will not reformat the array so that it will give the output that you expect when you try to print it.

If you want it to print the elements of the array, have your method return `String` instead, and use `return Arrays.toString(list)`.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.toString(list)` merely returns a `String` that is being printed at `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list))`, however in your first method you are just returning the Array without saving the result of `Arrays.toString(list)`. You're only printing `yourList.toString()`, so to say:

```
int[] myList = ... //initialize

String s = Arrays.toString(list); //Save the returned String in a variable

System.out.println(myList); //Prints myList.toString()

System.out.println(s); //Prints out the contents of the array
```

Comment: Word's a bit off, but it's the right idea (and that's a nitpick on my part ;))

Comment: Feel free to correct me. I'm a 3rd semester CS student and I'm trying to improve aswell, thats part of why I'm here answering stuff!

Comment: I'd aruge that *"//Prints out the actual array"* is a little off, it doesn't actually print the array, it prints a dump of the contents (by iterating through the array and calling `.toString()` on each element), but otherwise it's on the right track...

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
System.out.print(hello.create());
```

is evaluated by first invoking the create() method, the passing its return value (a reference to an object of type `int[]`) to the print() method of `System.out`. That method's Javadoc [reads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-):

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

and the Javadoc of `String.valueOf()` [reads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-):

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

Ok, our array reference isn't null, so what does its toString method do? The answer is in section 10.7 of the Java Language Specification, which [reads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The members of an array type are all of the following:
>
> - The public final field length, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be positive or zero.
> - The public method clone, which overrides the method of the same name in class Object and throws no checked exceptions. The return type of the clone method of an array type T[] is T[].
>
>   A clone of a multidimensional array is shallow, which is to say that it creates only a single new array. Subarrays are shared.
> - All the members inherited from class Object; the only method of Object that is not inherited is its clone method.

Therefore, the toString method must be inherited from Object. The Javadoc of Object.toString [reads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

... and that's why you see the type and hashCode of the array object when you print your array. (Incidentally, a hash code is not quite the same as a memory address. For one, several objects may have the same hash code; otherwise java would be limited to about 4 billion objects per application).

That's why Arrays.toString is a useful method to have, as it returns a String with the contents of the array. (You do invoke this method in create(), and it builds that String, but then you don't do anything with that String object, which is why it isn't printed).

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are running `Arrays.toString(list);` but youare throwing away the result (a single String), and returning the original value of `list`. `System.out.println` is then trying to convert the whole `int[]` array into a string, which it doesn't know how to do, so it is giving you the unexpected output.

In the second example, you are running the same utility function, but this time passing its output to `System.out.println`. The input to `System.out.println` is now the string you wanted.

What you need to do is make the `create` function return the `String` given by `Arrays.toString(list)`, rather than the original `int[]`.